# Executing Javascrpt after requests-html render

Tags: python, python-requests-html

How to execute a javascript after calling its `render()` function? The documentation just says to call it and no further explanation how to do the rest, for example clicking a button. Here is the original code from the documentation:

```
>>> r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')

>>> r.html.render()

>>> r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']
'<time>25</time>'
```

How can I find a button and execute the click event of it? I know how to do it in selenium. But it's not clear what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click()` function is not yet available, you can follow this [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/355) for update. Current solution is to inject the script and pass to `.render()`

```
r = session.get("http://....")

script = """
    () => {
       const button = document.querySelector("button");
       if(button) {
         button.click()
       }
    }
"""

r.html.render(script=script)
```